# How to connect to a Wi-Fi network that requires a special sign-in

Tags: wifi

In my residence there's a new Wi-Fi system.
We connect to this network that requires a password and then it is supposed to redirect us to a website that ask for another, personal password.

So far I have been able to connect my Samsung tablet and phone, after I connect there appears a message to sign-in to the Wi-Fi . 
But using my MacBook it's not the same: I type the first password and connect but there's not an option to sign-in.

I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Have you tried launching a web browser and visiting a website? Use something easy like cnn.com since sometimes https traffic can cause an authentication website to not redirect properly. Connect first, like you have done, then open a website in your browser (cnn.com). See if it will send you to your password page then and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem many times with my Mac at places like hotels and universities that use a web based login.

smoosher is on the right track. After the WiFi login, you need to go to a web site that does not use HTTPS. The New York Times is an example (http://nytimes.com). This will cause the redirect you need to the second login page. Sites that use or offer HTTPs probably won't work for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third-party browser, that might be the issue. Try opening Safari and go to a random page (e.g., [wikipedia.org](https://wikipedia.org)).